Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in - ski report error using WordPress and ACF Pro
I've looked through several questions here on stackoverflow but because I'm not fluent, I can't quite figure out how to fix the issue I'm having.
The website I'm working with has a feature of creating a conditions.xml file.
Here's the line of code causing an error (see below Error Details):
line 334: for ($k = ($lifts_open+1) ; $k <= 7; $k++){ 
    $current .= '<lift name="lift" status="closed" id="'.$k.'"/>';
}

Here's the line of code for the $lifts_open:
if(get_field('number_of_lifts_open')) {
    $lifts_open = get_field('number_of_lifts_open');
    } else {
        $lifts_open .= '--';
}

This code is pulling from a custom post type ACF field but if the user doesn't enter in a number (because there is no new snow) then I think that is why I'm getting this error email:

Error Details: An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 334 of the file /nas/content/live/ski/wp-content/themes/ski_theme/functions.php. Error message: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in /nas/content/live/ski/wp-content/themes/ski_theme/functions.php:334

I'm not 100% sure how to change the line 334 to make this work for PHP8+. I think there needs to be some sort of conditional statement that if it's null/0/-- then do something else! (haha)
Any recommendations are appreciated. Also, if you need more info on this file please let me know. THANK YOU!

$lifts_open appears to be a string. I'm not sure what get_field is returning, but you're appending '--' to it in the else. You cannot add 1 to a string.

Are you expecting concatenating -- to act like $variable-- and decrement the number when it's used? It doesn't work that way.

Thank you! Yes, the $lifts_open would have a number in there (how many lifts are open) but sometimes it's blank which would lead to a string of "--". I didn't write this code and it's from PHP7+ when it wasn't giving an error but with PHP8+, it sends a critical error email. So, I'm just not sure what the conditional should be if it's not a number but either "null" "--" or empty.

"but sometimes it's blank which would lead to a string of "--"" - because the code is explicitly appending those --. So make that $lifts_open = 0; instead in the else branch ...? (Or whatever the correct numeric starting value should be in that case.)

You are seemingly reusing the same $lifts_open variable for two different purposes: keep track of some numeric count you're incrementing and have a non-numeric label for certain use cases. That's messy because it leads to bugs and makes code hard to understand. You have two concepts, so use two variables.

With the following snippet I could reproduce your error:
<?php

$string001 = '';
$int001 = 1;

echo 'result: ' . ($string001 + $int001) . "\n\n";

Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + int in /home/user/scripts/code.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 6
(With null this error doesn't get triggered)
To avoid this error check first for empty string. Then you need to decide, if the loop has to get processed or not, in case you have an empty string. Therefor 2 possible solutions. 1st if you don't need the loop with empty string:
if ($lifts_open === '') {
    $lifts_open = 7;
}

Or in case the loop has to run:
if ($lifts_open === '') {
    $lifts_open = 0; // Or what ever you need here..
}

Or if null or 0 (zero) also must not process the loop, then the check can be as following:
if (empty($lifts_open)) {
    // what ever you need
}


A huge thank you for all of you that took the time to answer! I'm going to implement what was recommended above either with a conditional (empty) or just assigning the $lifts_open with '0'.
